# mysql group by and ratio between two sums

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum

I have a query which sums field 'value' from rows with foreign key value V1 and divides that sum with sum of the field 'value' from rows with foreign key value V2. Somehow I am getting wrong results. What am I doing wrong here?

```
SELECT 
    iv1.year, 
    1, 
    iv1.country_code, 
    SUM(iv1.value) / SUM(iv2.value) AS value, # Formula 
    'Added using stored procedure for creation of 1 indicator as ratio of 2 over 6 indicators' AS additional_info
FROM 
    indicators_values iv1
    JOIN indicators i1 ON (i1.no_of_indicator IN('B1.1.2.3', 'B1.2.2.2') 
            AND iv1.indicator_id = i1.indicator_id 
            AND i1.extracted_from_file_type = 'consolidated-a')
    JOIN indicators_values iv2 ON (iv2.country_code = iv1.country_code AND iv2.year = iv1.year)
    JOIN indicators i2 ON (i2.no_of_indicator IN('B1.1.2.2', 'B1.1.2.3', 'B1.1.2.4', 'B1.2.2.1', 'B1.2.2.2', 'B1.2.2.3') 
            AND iv2.indicator_id = i2.indicator_id 
            AND i2.extracted_from_file_type = 'consolidated-a')
WHERE 
    1=1 
    AND iv1.country_code = 'AT' 
    AND i1.no_of_indicator IN('B1.1.2.3', 'B1.2.2.2') 
    AND i2.no_of_indicator IN('B1.1.2.2', 'B1.1.2.3', 'B1.1.2.4', 'B1.2.2.1', 'B1.2.2.2', 'B1.2.2.3')
GROUP BY 
    iv1.year, iv1.country_code;
```

I know that I am getting wrong results, because most of the results that I am getting are bigger than 1, and they should all be smaller than 1, since I should have in the denominator same values contained in the numerator, plus some additional ones. Please advise? Thanks!

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schematically (too lazy to understand your conditions - maybe something is missing or changed places):

```
SELECT iv.year, 
       iv.country_code,
       (   SUM(CASE WHEN i.no_of_indicator IN('B1.1.2.3', 'B1.2.2.2')
                    THEN iv.value
                    END) 
         /
           SUM(CASE WHEN i.no_of_indicator IN('B1.1.2.2', 'B1.1.2.3', 'B1.1.2.4', 'B1.2.2.1', 'B1.2.2.2', 'B1.2.2.3')
                    THEN iv.value
                    END
       ) AS value

FROM indicators_values iv
JOIN indicators i ON iv.indicator_id = i.indicator_id 
WHERE i.extracted_from_file_type = 'consolidated-a'
  AND iv.country_code = 'AT' 
GROUP BY iv.year, iv.country_code
```

PS. Divisor may formally be zero - take care not to get a division by zero error.

Comment: Works! Thank you so much!

Comment: Could you please upvote my question so that it doesn't get deleted so that someone else can also profit from it? Thanks again! :)